# Bundle Install not installing the gems from gemfile

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I am trying to setup my rails application on Windows 7 machine. I installed Ruby 1.9.3 by using installer. I also installed Rails 3.2.2.

Now, I am trying to run bundle install from my application root directory. This command used to install all the required gems. However, when I am running in this new machine its not installing. I have to install all the gems manually one by one.

I know its bit strange but I am facing this for the first time..!!

Edit 1: Please refer below screen-shot.

Note: I have already installed few gems manually before posting here. The error related to DevKit that I am getting below has just came while I was tried to install json gem..

[image]

After Installing more gems manually:

[image]

Comment: Please post here output you have during bundle process.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error, it tells you that you need [DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/) to install that gem on Windows. So install that and follow the instructions, then try again ;) After the `json` gem can be installed, it should install every other gem in the `Gemfile`.

(The `json` gem is a dependency from Rails)

Comment: As i mentioned in Edit 1, i was getting this issue before this error came. Now, I have installed DevKit and Configured it properly. But still Bundle Install is not installing any gem by itself. I have to install each gem manually.

Comment: Now, I am done with installing all the gems manually..(HARD WAY)